# ANSYS pyMAPDL output from string to array

Tags: python-3.x, ansys-apdl

I'm studying ANSYS pyMAPDL, following the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szHmg-xW_hM&t=1s

It was understood from both the tutorial code itself and pyMAPDL documentation that prnsol returns a str object, but it has the enriched method to_list() which allows the output to be exported to list format. https://mapdldocs.pyansys.com/user_guide/post.html

However, when I run the following line from the sample code, it just reports attribute error

`mapdl_s_1_list = mapdl.prnsol('S', 'PRIN',).to_list()`

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_list'

If I print out the prnsol() result, it contains both the header and table, I have to do some processing in order to extra the table information for further processing.

Would like to know if there is a quick fix to make the enriched method work? Thanks!

hawkoli1987

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

The version of PyMAPDL used needed updating from 0.60.6 to 0.60.7 (feature was introduced in 0.60.7).  See here: https://github.com/pyansys/pymapdl/discussions/1395

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34322373)

Comment: Hi @CreepyRaccoon Sorry - hope my edited answer is clearer.  Mike